# Automatically Move Backlog to Sprint JIRA

Tags: jira

Our live website team works only on hot fixes, so there is no need for a backlog. We integrate our JIRA with ZenDesk and support agents can escalate these website issues into JIRA directly, but the problem is that these issues go to the backlog, and there doesn't seem to be any way to assign them to a sprint using the ZenDesk integration. It is tedious to have to go into JIRA for every issue and move it to the backlog, and most of our agents don't even have access to JIRA so it slows down the entire process of getting website issues fixed. Is there a way to auto push items from the backlog into the sprint, or do just do away with the backlog entirely for a single project?

Comment: The solution from Niels above is probably the best, but if a Kanban board is not suitable for your organisation then is it possible to simply assign the issue to a sprint on creation of the issue using the 'Sprint' field within the Jira ticket? This should bypass the backlog and drop the ticket directly into the sprint.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [**Kanban board**](https://confluence.atlassian.com/agile/glossary/kanban-board) instead of the Sprints version. Just [create a new board](https://confluence.atlassian.com/agile/jira-agile-user-s-guide/creating-a-board) in your project and choose Kanban.

The difference is that the Kanban board shows all project issues in the first todo column. This first column is then your backlog. You are still free to rank the issues with drag-and-drop.

This removes the need to drag issues into a Sprint, but you can use the Jira boards features and workflows.